# jhipster rest api: curl example shown by swagger-ui not working

Tags: curl, jhipster, swagger-ui

Just getting stuck when trying to invoke the generated REST-API using the curl example as shown by the swagger-ui.

curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN: 69b86f52-c3a4-4c06-ae9f-baebee0a01f2' 'http://localhost:8080/api/users'

Can anyone help me here. Am I missing something ? Is there some call required to obtain a session cookie first ?

kind regards,
Dirk Dinger

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SimpleCorsFilter Error. İts true?

Answer (score 0):

if you use session authentication type in JHipster then yes you must authenticate first with curl on `/api/authentication` with login/password to obtain a `jsessionid` cookie which maps to an authenticated session. This is already done when you use swagger-ui in browser.